# where there is a padding in this case

Tags: html, css

This is the result![enter image description here][1]

Please look at the empty space circled red , why is that please?

this is the html

```
<div id="map_manual_address_container">
                <div id="map_canvas"></div>
                <div id="mamual_address">
                    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and this is the css

```
#map_manual_address_container {
    width:700px;
    height:410px;
}


#map_canvas { width: 400px; height: 400px; 
              float:left;
}


#mamual_address {
    float:right;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Your adress container is 700, while your canvas is 400, so yea, its technically leaving 300 pixels free. If you want the button to fill in, change your float right to left (and make it an inline element). That should do the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution

```
#manual_address {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your #map_manual_address_container has a width of 700 and the feildset has a padding of 30 horizontally. Since you've set:

```
#msform fieldset {
box-sizing : border-box;
width: 80%;
}
```

The feildset's area including the padding is set to 80% of #map_manual_address_container width which means that #map_manual_address_container will be wider than #msform so floating to the right of the #msform will result in the address text area being outside the feildset. To fix this remove one of

```
box-sizing : border-box;
width: 80%;
```

This should stop the feildset being wider than #map_manual_address_container.

Comment: I have a screenshot to explain this, however my reputation is not high enough to allow me to post it.

Comment: I appreciate your help and support, However, the problem is solved now. Bty you can use `jsfiddle.net` to provide your code. +1 many thanks